# SQL Left Join not working with char data type based on conditional value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables Nationality and Student. Both tables joined by NationalityID char(3). char holds the spaces like: '1  '.  here total 3 chars for both tables. but no result even though they have same common value. i have also trim the blank space but no result. please see the query.

```
SELECT S.StudentID,N.NationalityName
FROM [dbo].[Student] S
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Nationality] N  
ON S.NationalityID=N.NationalityID
WHERE S.StudentID=232

--No Output
```

After using RTRIM()

```
SELECT S.StudentID,N.NationalityName
FROM [dbo].[Student] S
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Nationality] N  
ON RTRIM(S.NationalityID)=RTRIM(N.NationalityID)
WHERE S.StudentID=232

--No Output
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Also please confirm if you are having any relation in Nationality id from both the tables

Comment: Do one thing execute simple select statement with RTRIM on column and check both table values are same or not?

Comment: Sorry guys, its working with different student ID.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, they don't have the same value and you should fix the data.  One possible problem is spaces at the beginning and/or end.  If so, try:

```
SELECT S.StudentID, N.NationalityName
FROM [dbo].[Student] S LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[Nationality] N  
     ON LTRIM(RTRIM(S.NationalityID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(N.NationalityID))
WHERE S.StudentID = 232;
```

I'm not so confident that this will work.  Assuming that the values are ASCII characters, you can use the ASCII function to see what is really being stored:

```
SELECT S.NationalityID, ASCII(LEFT(S.NationalityID, 1)),
       ASCII(SUBSTRING(S.NationalityID, 2, 1)),
       ASCII(RIGHT(S.NationalityID, 1))
FROM Student s;
```

Once you have figured this out, then fix the data so the joins will work.  By the way, you would not be having this problem if `NationalityID` were an identity column.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Not Working with '1'  when only one characters